# phpMyAdmin "A fatal JavaScript error has occurred. Would you like to send an error report?"

Tags: phpmyadmin

I upgraded phpMyAdmin to latest version in ubuntu 18.04. After that, I frequently get this error message. I reinstalled it to v4.9.5 and again from latest source. Still I get this error everytime I login to phpmyadmin. This is the same case in chrome, firefox and in their incognito modes.

```
{
"pma_version": "5.0.2",
"browser_name": "CHROME",
"browser_version": "84.0.4147.105",
"user_os": "Linux",
"server_software": "nginx/1.14.0",
"user_agent_string": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36",
"locale": "en",
"configuration_storage": "disabled",
"php_version": "7.2.33-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1",
"script_name": "index.php",
"exception_type": "js",
"exception": {
    "mode": "stack",
    "name": "ReferenceError",
    "message": "isStorageSupported is not defined",
    "stack": [
        {
            "func": "HTMLDocument.",
            "line": "1052",
            "column": "9",
            "context": [
                "        incInterval = window.setInterval(SetIdleTime, 1000);",
                "        var sessionTimeout = Math.min(",
                "            CommonParams.get('LoginCookieValidity'),",
                "            CommonParams.get('session_gc_maxlifetime')",
                "        );",
                "        if (isStorageSupported('sessionStorage')) {",
                "            window.sessionStorage.setItem('guid', guid());",
                "        }",
                "        var interval = (sessionTimeout - 5) * 1000;",
                "        if (interval > Math.pow(2, 31) - 1) { // max value for setInterval(//...",
                "            interval = Math.pow(2, 31) - 1;"
            ],
            "uri": "js/functions.js?v=5.0.2",
            "scriptname": "js/functions.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "HTMLDocument.dispatch",
            "line": "2",
            "column": "42571",
            "context": [
                "/*! jQuery v3.4.1 | (c) JS Foundation and other contributors | jquery.org/l//...",
                "!function(e,t){\"use strict\";\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof modul//...",
                ""
            ],
            "uri": "js/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js?v=5.0.2",
            "scriptname": "js/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "HTMLDocument.$event.dispatch",
            "line": "374",
            "column": "19",
            "context": [
                "$event.dispatch = function( event ){",
                "\tif ( $.data( this, \"suppress.\"+ event.type ) - new Date().getTime() > 0 ){",
                "\t\t$.removeData( this, \"suppress.\"+ event.type );",
                "\t\treturn;",
                "\t}",
                "\treturn $dispatch.apply( this, arguments );",
                "};",
                "",
                "// event fix hooks for touch events...",
                "var touchHooks = ",
                "$event.fixHooks.touchstart = "
            ],
            "uri": "js/vendor/jquery/jquery.event.drag-2.2.js?v=5.0.2",
            "scriptname": "js/vendor/jquery/jquery.event.drag-2.2.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "HTMLDocument.v.handle",
            "line": "2",
            "column": "40572",
            "context": [
                "/*! jQuery v3.4.1 | (c) JS Foundation and other contributors | jquery.org/l//...",
                "!function(e,t){\"use strict\";\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof modul//...",
                ""
            ],
            "uri": "js/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js?v=5.0.2",
            "scriptname": "js/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "Object.trigger",
            "line": "2",
            "column": "70627",
            "context": [
                "/*! jQuery v3.4.1 | (c) JS Foundation and other contributors | jquery.org/l//...",
                "!function(e,t){\"use strict\";\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof modul//...",
                ""
            ],
            "uri": "js/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js?v=5.0.2",
            "scriptname": "js/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "HTMLDocument.",
            "line": "2",
            "column": "71222",
            "context": [
                "/*! jQuery v3.4.1 | (c) JS Foundation and other contributors | jquery.org/l//...",
                "!function(e,t){\"use strict\";\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof modul//...",
                ""
            ],
            "uri": "js/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js?v=5.0.2",
            "scriptname": "js/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "Function.each",
            "line": "2",
            "column": "2777",
            "context": [
                "/*! jQuery v3.4.1 | (c) JS Foundation and other contributors | jquery.org/l//...",
                "!function(e,t){\"use strict\";\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof modul//...",
                ""
            ],
            "uri": "js/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js?v=5.0.2",
            "scriptname": "js/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "jQuery.fn.init.each",
            "line": "2",
            "column": "1419",
            "context": [
                "/*! jQuery v3.4.1 | (c) JS Foundation and other contributors | jquery.org/l//...",
                "!function(e,t){\"use strict\";\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof modul//...",
                ""
            ],
            "uri": "js/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js?v=5.0.2",
            "scriptname": "js/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "jQuery.fn.init.trigger",
            "line": "2",
            "column": "71198",
            "context": [
                "/*! jQuery v3.4.1 | (c) JS Foundation and other contributors | jquery.org/l//...",
                "!function(e,t){\"use strict\";\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof modul//...",
                ""
            ],
            "uri": "js/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js?v=5.0.2",
            "scriptname": "js/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "Object.fireOnload",
            "line": "119",
            "column": "21",
            "context": [
                "     *",
                "     * @return void",
                "     */",
                "    fireOnload: function (file) {",
                "        var eventName = 'onload_' + AJAX.hash(file);",
                "        $(document).trigger(eventName);",
                "        if (this.debug) {",
                "            // eslint-disable-next-line no-console",
                "            console.log(",
                "                // no need to translate",
                "                'Fired event ' + eventName + ' for file ' + file"
            ],
            "uri": "js/ajax.js?v=5.0.2",
            "scriptname": "js/ajax.js"
        }
    ],
    "uri": "index.php?"
}
```

}

The error causes no response to mouse clicks and I'm stuck in it.